# Android aws cognito Invalid login token. Not a Cognito token

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to make aws android cognito work with only `developer authenticated identities`. But getting the below exception (sdk version 2.2.16).

I have cross checked identityId and identityPoolId and both values are correct.

In the loginsMap, I am using key as "`cognito-identity.amazonaws.com`" and token as the openId token received from my server back end.

The loginsMap is being set in the refresh and getIdentityId method of my android `AWSAbstractCognitoDeveloperIdentityProvider` class.

Anybody facing this kind of similar issue ?

```
com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.NotAuthorizedException: Invalid login token. Not a Cognito token. (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: NotAuthorizedException; Request ID: a270a26a-18fa-11e6-add3-c1b3dbd555de)
                                                                    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:716)
                                                                    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:392)
                                                                    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:199)
                                                                    at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.invoke(AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.java:533)
                                                                    at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.getCredentialsForIdentity(AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.java:468)
                                                                    at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.populateCredentialsWithCognito(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:627)
                                                                    at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.startSession(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:553)
                                                                    at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.refresh(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:503)
                                                                    at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.refresh(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.java:463)
                                                                    at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.getIdentityId(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.java:414)
                                                                    at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.populateCredentialsWithCognito(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:621)
                                                                    at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.startSession(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:553)
                                                                    at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.refresh(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:503)
                                                                    at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.refresh(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.java:463)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put the developer provider name as key in the logins map and the SDK will take care of rotating that to "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com" for you if required.

Another thing you must do is update the identity id that you get from your back end along with the token. If the identity id in the SDK cache is A and the token says it belongs to identity id B, we will throw "Not a Cognito token." error. Ideally you should use the [update()](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/blob/master/CognitoSyncDemo/src/com/amazonaws/cognito/sync/demo/DeveloperAuthenticationProvider.java#L106) method to update both identity id and token after they are refreshed from your back end.

[Developer Authenticated Identities](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html) explains this in more detail. You should also look at the flow in our [sample app](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/blob/master/CognitoSyncDemo/src/com/amazonaws/cognito/sync/demo/DeveloperAuthenticationTask.java). Hope this helps.

Comment: I have kept update(identityid, token)  in refresh as well as getidentityid method. Also, the same identityid and token received from my server, if I try from iOS SDK it works. And I have used the same code as provided in the sample app.

Comment: But sample app does not set "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com" in the logins map. It adds the developer provider name in the logins map in [DeveloperAuthenticationTask](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/blob/master/CognitoSyncDemo/src/com/amazonaws/cognito/sync/demo/DeveloperAuthenticationTask.java#L54). Did you change that too?

Comment: Yeah, I removed "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com" and instead using the provider name. And it is working now. Thanks for your help !!

Comment: @ChetanMehta, where can we find latest aws cognito ios sdk samples ? The latest version of SDK is 2.4.1, but the samples are using 2.2.X . And there has been lot of changes between these 2 versions. Please let me know any working sample/example using iOS SDK 2.4.1.

Comment: @ChetanMehta I am facing similar issue, when I leave the app in background for long period, the token is getting expired throwing exactly OP error. Yes I have exception handler for IoT backend and there it is working fine